# Best Approach for JPA lazy loading over Rest/AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, jpa, eclipselink

Sorry for the general question, but is there an approach for still using JPA lazy loading of entities, when developing a restful AngularJS application.

In the old JSF days, it would all just work when a backing bean accessed the list.

I am using EclipseLink and Spring Data, with Jersey for the restful end points.

Regards

I

Answer (score 0):

Generally you'd have to trigger the lazy loading of the entities prior the `EntityManager` being closed during the lifecycle of the request.

To do so, you can use the "Open EntityManager in View" pattern. Spring provides a `Filter` you can apply: `OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter` (read the docs here: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.0.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/support/OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.html).

Alternatively, you can manually call `getMyLazyCollection()` on your JPA entity(ies) prior to serializing them to JSON.

Comment: Whether you are using `OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter` or implicitly resolve the `getMyLazyCollection()` you are suggesting that the whole entity will be resolved server side before returning that JSON ?

Comment: The Entity needs to be resolved at some point on the server side. So that'll happen during JSON serialization (traversing the object graph) if you have the EntityManager open during that time (via the filter), or just prior to JSON serialization if you explicitly invoke the getter method. You can of course, mark the entity's lazy collection as not serializable (by Jackson2) via `@JsonIgnore` and then make an additional call to the server to get the collection, if you wish. Not sure how that fits into your exact use case though.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best course depends on following.

> Are you able to retrieve the fully resolved entity i.e. all of its
>   components without adversely affecting performance ?

If the answer is `Yes` then go for resolving the full entity using JPA fetch option=eager.

I the answer is `No`. I would go for the following approach:-

1) Expose every lazy JPA component/association explicitly as a `sub-resource`.

e.g.

```
  @Entity
  public class Employee {
      @Id
      private long id;
      ...
      @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
      @JoinColumn(name="ADDR_ID")
      private Address homeAddress;
      ...
    }
    @Entity
    public class Address{
    }
```

2) Expose service as controller(although you can have them separated but I don't recommend)

```
@RequestMapping(value="/api/employee")
@Controller
public class EmployeeSvc

       public Employee getEmployee(@PathVariable empID){
        .....
       } 

       @RequestMapping(value="{empID}/homeaddress")
       public Address getHomeAddress(@PathVariable empID){
          // will serve http://localhost:8080/api/employee/11111/homeaddress
          return this.getEmployee(empID).getHomeAddress();
           //make sure you are using 2nd Level cache - as you retrieve object twice         
       } 

}
```

Comment: Good points @bhantol, why load a collection in the resource if you don't need it? Make it a sub-resource in the API. Cool.